# mongodump not working on replica set protocol version 1

Tags: replicaset, mongodump

I was doing `mongodump --host=replicasetname/host,host,host -d databasename --out=path` and it works fine, ever.

But I have made a new replicaset, and when I do the same, I get nothing.

this happens when it works:

```
2016-02-10T11:58:29.152+0100 starting new replica set monitor for replica set ... with seeds ...:27017,...:27017,...:27017
2016-02-10T11:58:29.152+0100 creating new connection to:...:27017
2016-02-10T11:58:29.152+0100 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] BackgroundJob starting: ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher
2016-02-10T11:58:29.152+0100 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
2016-02-10T11:58:29.213+0100 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2016-02-10T11:58:29.275+0100 connected to server ...:27017 (...)
2016-02-10T11:58:29.275+0100 connected connection!
2016-02-10T11:58:29.339+0100 changing hosts to ... from ...
connected to: ...
2016-02-10T11:58:29.339+0100 creating new connection to:...
2016-02-10T11:58:29.400+0100 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2016-02-10T11:58:29.460+0100 connected to server ...
2016-02-10T11:58:29.460+0100 connected connection!
2016-02-10T11:58:29.521+0100 DATABASE: ...   to     ...
2016-02-10T11:58:29.648+0100    ....system.indexes to /tmp/dump/...
...
...
```

this happens when it does not work

```
2016-02-10T12:03:02.181+0100 starting new replica set monitor for replica set ... with seeds ...
2016-02-10T12:03:02.181+0100 creating new connection to:...
2016-02-10T12:03:02.181+0100 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] BackgroundJob starting: ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher
2016-02-10T12:03:02.181+0100 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
2016-02-10T12:03:02.192+0100 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2016-02-10T12:03:02.258+0100 connected to server ...
2016-02-10T12:03:02.258+0100 connected connection!
connected to: ...
2016-02-10T12:03:02.323+0100 creating new connection to:...
2016-02-10T12:03:02.323+0100 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2016-02-10T12:03:02.386+0100 connected to server ...
2016-02-10T12:03:02.386+0100 connected connection!
2016-02-10T12:03:02.450+0100 DATABASE: ...   to     ...
```

The out folder are created, but it is empty.

There are no errors showed.
The database exists, and it han collections and documents

Their configuration is different though

this one works

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

This other do not
    {
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "settings" : {
            "chainingAllowed" : true,
            "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
            "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
            "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
            "getLastErrorModes" : {

```
        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

What is happening here?
What can I do?

Thanks